# How can I concatenate an integer with desired times in C?

Tags: c, function, integer, concatenation

I want to write a function like this:

```
int number_maker(int n, int k)
{
    if(k==1)
        return n;
    else
    {
        int x = 10;

        while(n >= x)
            x *= 10;

        return (n*x) + number_maker(n,k-1) ;
    }
}
```

For an example, let's say my number is `350`. I want to make it based on 
a repeated parameter. I can make it `350350` but when it comes to more repetitions like 3 or 4 times, it goes wrong.

I can't use standard C functions.

Comment: Please show the code you currently have. Why can't you use standard C functions?

Comment: Because we have not yet learned yet and we can't use the functions that we have not learned in class.

Comment: OK. Make sure to format your code properly. The block that you currently have pasted into your question is an example of one of my biggest pet peeves.

Comment: I formatted it for you in an edit. Please review.

Comment: If you can't use standard C functions, then this is as good as you can get (if you're required to use an `int`).

Comment: An 32 bit  `int` can only accommodate all decimal integers up-to 9 digits and some 10 digit numbers (max value being 2147483647), so how do you propose you could repeat a three digit sequence 4 times?  Not possible - you need to use strings perhaps?  Or a uint64_t which will allow 18 digits.

Comment: This is the least practical way to get the result you are wanting to achieve, and looks more like a school exercise in learning recursion than anything that is useful in any practical sense.  And given the stringent limitation on integers, it is really a surprisingly poor assignment, if it were that.....

Answer (score 1):

Your program is trying to store a number greater than `INT_MAX` in an `int`, which results in an overflow during conversion. Even if you modify your function to have a `size_t` return type, that will only get you so far. The only way to be sure that your program produces accurate output is to store the concatenated integer as a `char*` and return that, instead.

Comment: but because the function is recursive, he can pass the concatenated integer on as a `char*`, but the moment he unwraps that to do the math again it will just crash again.  based on what he is trying to output, there shouldn't be any math involved anyway, which is just as important as the storage type, imo.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that he attempt to convert from `char*` back to `int`, nor that math be used. In fact, there's no need to use recursion for this, either, a simple `for` loop will do.

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to repeat any three digit repetition in a 32-bit `int`, three times, it is not possible to fit four repetitions as only all 9 digit decimal integers can be represented.

Your problem with three repetitions is because on each recursion `x` is always 1000 (for a three digit n), whereas you actually need it to be 1000000 on the second recursion.  Solving that is somewhat cumbersome, but you need to pass `x` into the `number_maker` thus:

```
int number_maker(int n, int k, int x)  // <<< additional parameter
{
    if(k==1)
        return n;
    else
    {
       int xx = x ;                    // <<< added
       while(n * xx >= x)              // <<< modified
            x *= 10;

        return (n*x) + number_maker(n,k-1, x) ;
    }
}
```

Then a call such as:

```
printf("%d", number_maker( 350, 3, 1 ) );
```

will work.  It is cumbersome because you have to pass an initial `x` value, and that can only be `1`.  In C++ you could use an default argument to hide that.

It will not work however for 4 repetitions or a three digit decimal integer.

That said:

```
printf("%d", number_maker( 1, 9, 1 ) );
printf("%d", number_maker( 9, 9, 1 ) );
```

work ok.  You can get away with 10 repetitions only for `n==1`.

```
printf("%d", number_maker( 1, 10, 1 ) );
```

Essentially it works for *all* 9 digit results and (less usefully) *some* 10 digit results.

Using unsigned integers would increase the number of 10 digit results that could be represented, but that is not particularly useful perhaps.